# Drarry fanfic where Draco is kept under Harry's care in Hogwarts and Harry abuses him but still loves him

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

I don't remember the name of this fanfic and I've been searching for it for weeks. The fic, from what I remember, goes this way -

It is a Hogwarts fanfic, meaning, Draco, Harry and all others attend Hogwarts but I don't remember if it is an 8th year fic or pre 8th year fic. I just know they're in Hogwarts while this fic goes on. Lucius and Narcissa are arrested before Draco goes home for holidays and the ministry confiscates the Malfoy Manor. Then, Draco is put under Harry's jurisdiction by the ministry. The ministry even decides the clothes Draco wears! They're all second hand clothes, way too loose for him. Once, he walks into the great hall with pink robes and he feels utterly humiliated.

There's this scene where Draco snaps at Ronald and Hermione before entering the library along with the golden trio. Then, Harry tells his friends to go wait inside the library and slaps Draco hard across the face. Hermione notices the slap mark on Draco's cheek after Harry and Draco joins them and tries to reason with Harry about his "abuse" towards Draco.

There is also another very humiliating scene which I can recollect. Harry has to go somewhere so he asks Draco to kneel in the center of his room. He orders Draco to not move coz if he does, Harry will know. Harry's gone for a very long time, causing Draco to lose control over his bladder and wet himself. When Harry finally returns, he finds Draco crying.

Once, somewhere in the middle of the fanfic, Ronald walks in on Harry having intercourse with Draco, against the wall. Harry doesn't stop though Draco feels humiliated.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (Fanfic) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fanfic-story-id-question)

Comment: Why is "abuse" in quotation marks?

Comment: @Adamant: Probably because, in some subcultures, this is rough love. Can't say how accurate that is here.

Comment: I'm stunned that two fanfics were found closely matching the OP's description.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - In responsible BDSM circles, everything has to be consensual and agreed upon beforehand (the famous SSC). Humiliation, emotional manipulation, physical abuse, and all the Fifty Shades of Gray type stuff is not considered acceptable. That is, Draco could agree to have Harry slap him as part of some scenario, but if Harry just decides to slap him to frighten him, that's still unethical.  Of course, abusive BDSM exists too, just like abusive mainstream sex.

Answer (score 4):

Found your fic, "[Unexpected Consequences](https://archiveofourown.org/works/3697037/chapters/8194853)" by lauren3210, and it's a doozy.

> He’d been told the specifics of the spell when his choice had been laid out before him: either join his parents in Azkaban, or submit to being bound to someone who would have almost complete control over him for a year.

Draco lusts after Harry

> Draco wanted to believe that this was the sole reason for him requesting Potter to be his bonded guard, but he’d had plenty of time for soul searching while being detained ever since his trial. The truth was that Draco had longed for some of Potter’s attention since the moment he’d heard that the other boy was on the Hogwart’s train, their very first year of school. It hadn’t seemed to matter if it was good or bad, he’d just wanted Potter to see him, to acknowledge him in some small way. And now, if Potter agreed to this, Draco would have a whole year of that attention, and maybe once it was done and he was finally a free man, that craving to be noticed by Potter will have finally been sated.

Draco's parents visit Azerbaijan(Azkaban)

> With both his parents locked up as well, he wouldn’t even have the luxury of the occasional visit to break up the monotony.

Eight Year at Hogwarts

> Life at school as an Eighth Year student was both exactly the same and completely different, Draco found out quickly. He still ate his meals in the Great Hall, still got bored during classes. Madam Pince was still a little bit weird about her books and the rumour mill still ran quicker than an open tap. It felt the same, moving from one class to another, putting on the same tie and practising the same wand movements, waiting until the last minute to finish up the last two inches of homework for the next day’s class.

Draco's intercourse

> The tempo picked up slowly, Harry’s fingers digging into Draco’s hips as he began to pull Draco up to meet his every thrust. Sweat began to build up between the slide of their bodies, Harry’s chest hair scratching tantalisingly against Draco’s nipples. Their kiss turned to sharing heated breaths, ratcheting up the heat between them as they moved inexorably closer to their completion. Harry moaned once, the sound petering out into a quiet gasp as his body went taut and his hips snapped forwards once, twice, three times and then stilled, and Draco moaned at the feeling of wet warmth spilling inside him. The door to the Gryffindor Boys dormitory opened and Ron walked in. "Bloody hell!", he yelped as he saw Harry's seed spilling out of Draco, but Harry did not stop ramming his hard cock into Draco.

Harry seems reluctant at first but he quickly becomes a sociopath. Interesting concept.

Comment: Oh my goodness, reading about abusive people presented as heroes is not my favorite thing. Though, seeing as it seems to be partly a pornographic fic, I guess it doesn't necessarily represent the author's real ethics. Still, it's clearly the right fanfiction, so +1.

Answer (score 2):

The fic you asked for is "[What Goes Around](https://archiveofourown.org/works/711608?view_full_work=true)" by TuckerPuppy(HarleyD)

It's a 6th year fic and not 8th year fic.

1. Draco is home for holidays only to find his parents gone. Lucius actually betrays his own son.

> "Father?" There was a long pause as Draco set down his bag and looked around the front room of the mansion. He wasn't happy, his father had obviously forgotten that he was coming home and had not picked him up at the train station. He had to take the filthy knight bus home and his father would buy him something expense to make up for it.
>   He stamped his foot, his voice rising, "Father!" Still nothing. An uneasy feeling was starting to rise in him, a house elf at least should have greeted him at the door. He left his bag where he dropped it and moved further into the house, looking for any sign of his father or mother.
>
> "Mother? Father didn't pick me up!" He stopped moving, realizing there was no sound anywhere else in the mansion. He cleared his throat, "Uh, house elves?" When none appeared he realized that something was very wrong.

2. Ministry/Dumbledore decides the clothes Draco wears.

> He was still reeling from finding that Snape was gone and he only caught the end of the statement, but it was enough to remind him about the other major annoyance in his life. "What about my clothes sir?"
>
> "You will continue to wear clothing the ministry has provided you with, that too is found on your dorm room bed. All property from the Malfoy fortunes has been confiscated, a special exception was made for your books."

3. Also, Ministry doesn't place Malfoy under Harry's care. It is Harry who offers him a place by his side rather cruelly by saving him in the great hall. Harry is rather dark towards Malfoy in this fic almost until the end.

> "But don't worry princess, when things get bad, and they will get bad," for a moment something like regret passed through his eyes, "I'll be there for a price. I've been known to protect the helpless."
>
> Harry abruptly let him go and left, leaving Draco still sputtering over being called princess. It was only after his temper settled that he realized that Harry had sounded like he was warning him about something and he got the distinct feeling that he had missed something.

4. Draco's clothes are turned pink and he walks into the Great Hall wearing pink clothes.

> Draco’s arrival to the great hall was met with laughter, and he awkwardly ducked his head, going towards the Gryffindor table. Honestly even Harry was speechless when his eyes landed on him, but it only lasted a moment before the laughter started.
>
> Draco frowned, sliding into his seat on Harry’s left. “Yea, yea. Hilarious.” He crossed his arms angrily, pink shirt fluttering. It wasn’t just his shirt either, his pants were pink, his shoes… he looked like a giant ball of cotton candy.
>   “Er, you know you’re wearing all pink, right?”
>   He tugged self-consciously at the clothes, “Zeke turned everything I have pink.” He bit his lip, giving Harry big eyes, “Can you please change them back?”

5. Library scene - Harry only tells Ron to get in before slapping Draco because 'Mione is already inside.

> “Ron, go on inside, I’ll be right in.” Ron looked between them worriedly, but Harry gave him a warm smile, “Go on. I just wanna ask him a question.
>
> He finally conceded, comforted that nothing was gonna happen by the bright smile Harry was giving him. Draco wasn’t fooled at all and knew what was gonna happen the minute Ron was out of sight. The slap was fast, hard, and not completely unexpected. He raised his hand to his stinging cheek, gritting his teeth as he pushed down the urge to hit him back.
>
> “Don’t push me Draco. Now get in the library.”
>
> Mione was already there. She looked up and smiled, but it quickly slipped off her face. He reached up, as if he could cover the mark, and slipped into the seat across from Ron.

6. Harry makes him kneel on the ground for too long. Draco wets himself.

> Harry finally turned his attention back to him and pointed to the ground. Without hesitation or question he kneeled. He flinched as Harry moved towards him but the other boy only touched his fingers to Draco’s hair, tucking the growing strands behind his ear. “Stay right here. You can sit on your heels or kneel up straight or go to all fours if you feel like it but you stay right here and you stay on your knees. There is no reason to move from this spot Draco, you understand that?”
>
> .....It all would have been fine and good but he could feel an annoying urge rising up in him as he cast a wistful glance in the direction of the bathroom.
>
> .....By the fourth hour Draco was getting a little desperate. He pressed the heel of his hand between his legs, desperately trying to curb the urge to need the loo.
>
> .....When he heard Harry enter his eyes snapped up and Harry could see the fear in them. He wasn’t even halfway to him when Draco’s voice, watery with tears spoke up, “I’m s-sorry, I tried to… I couldn’t help it…”
>
> At first he had thought that Draco had moved from his spot but a quick glance around at his detection spells told him that the boy hadn’t moved at all. He didn’t understand what was wrong until he got closer and wrinkled his nose at the smell of … urine. With frightening clarity he realized what must have happened.

7. Also, it wasn't Ron who walks in on Harry and Draco having intercourse against a wall. It was Blaise. And, Harry permits the man into their room.

> He was going to ignore it, already pressing inside Draco when Blaise’s voice could be heard through the door, “Potter!”
>
> Something in his voice was enough to make Harry hesitate, especially since Blaise was already coming to Harry after discretion had been stressed. Especially when him being just outside their door meant Blaise had already somehow managed to get into the Gryffindor dorm. He snarled, “What?”
>
> "We gotta talk. Now!”
>
> Harry sighed, Blaise sounded almost scared and he winked at Draco. “Yea, come in.”
>
> Draco squealed as the door swung open, and Harry still held him against the wall, very nearly inside him. Blaise froze when he realized what was going on and turned red. Harry grinned at Draco’s outraged expression as he held him there for a second longer before letting him go. He tucked himself away with minor difficulty as Draco scrambled to pull his pants on.

Ultimately, it's a very long and very dark fic. Damn.